Angular ShadowDom pull in style tags from other mixed encapsulation modes
I have a specific component I want to use Shadow Dom with to completely isolate it from external styles (most of the other components use the default emulated view encapsulation).
However, I noticed that rather than isolating this component from other styles, Angular placed <style> tags from all the other components INTO the Shadow Dom component. This  completely removes the point of using shadow dom.
After banging my head for a while, I found that in the documentation, this is apparently expected behavior (Angular 17 doc) for Angular. I'm at a loss as to why this is desired, as it also results in an incredible amount of DOM bloat for each instance of this component being used, but regardless, I need to create a component that is insulated from external styles.
I have a repro set up here
Is there a way to properly completely insulate an Angular component from other component styles with Shadow Dom? I'm about to just do this whole thing manually.
I've tried looking at the ViewEncapsulation modes, but apparently it is "expected" behavior.
According to the docs reasoning for copying styles:

This approach may seem counter-intuitive at first, but without it a component with ViewEncapsulation.None could not be used within a component with ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom, since its styles would not be available.

This is a huge (and misguided) assumption on how developers will always be using Shadow Dom. Shadow Dom is design to provide insulation, and that insulation should be provided when asked. If there are special cases of needing to pull in styles, the developer should either handle that manually (since they're using a feature that is designed for isolation), or not use Shadow Dom at all (a more realistic scenario probably).
Let me clarify. This does not have to do with styles from the parent being inherited and applied (like this question is about). This is about how Angular actually places <style> tags inside shadow components egregiously.

let me know if the duplicate answer does not solve your issue, I will reopen the question

@NarenMurali, unfortunately, this issue is different. That question had more to do with the nature of shadow dom and how styles can be inherited from the host (nothing to do with the <style> tags). That's all part of the spec. This issue, however, has to deal with the fact that Angular actually places <style> tags in shadow components by default.

@NarenMurali, please re-open this question, as it is not a duplicate. See previous comment :)

the styles are inherited from the parent, it is as per w3 guidelines as the duplicate answer mentioned, here is a codepen demo where the same happens, codepen hope this solves your problem

@NarenMurali, I appreciate reopening. Please re-read the question. I added a clarifying note at the end explicitly indicating that is NOT the question I am asking. This has nothing to do with inheriting styles, and everything to do with Angular placing stylesheet nodes inside a component (which is not the same as inheriting styles)

There is a codepen I linked in the question that shows exactly what the issue I'm talking about shows.
